# Regex to match following pattern in SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I am trying to extract parts of a MySQL query to get the information I want.

I used this code / regex in Python:

```
import re
query = "SELECT `asd`.`ssss` as `column1`, `ss`.`wwwwwww` from `table`"
table_and_columns = re.findall('\`.*?`[.]\`.*?`',query)
```

My expected output:

```
['`asd`.`ssss`', `ss`.`wwwwwww`']
```

My real output:

```
['`asd`.`ssss`', '`column1`, `ss`.`wwwwwww`']
```

Can anybody help me and explain me where I went wrong?
The regex should only find the ones that have two strings like `asd` and a dot in the middle.

PS: I know that this is not a valid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` can also match a backtick, so the pattern starts by matching a backtick and is able to match all chars until it reaches the literal dot in `[.]`

There is no need to use non greedy quantifiers, you can use a negated character class only prevent crossing the backtick boundary.

```
`[^`]*`\.`[^`]*`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DRQzqK/1)

The asterix `*` matches 0 or more times. If there has to be at least a single char, and newlines and spaces are unwanted, you could add `\s` to prevent matching whitespace chars and use `+` to match 1 or more times.

```
`[^`\s]+`\.`[^`\s]+`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yn85q/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UhFXVA)

For example

```
import re
query = "SELECT `asd`.`ssss` as `column1`, `ss`.`wwwwwww` from `table`"
table_and_columns = re.findall('`[^`\s]+`\.`[^`\s]+`',query)
print(table_and_columns)
```

Output

```
['`asd`.`ssss`', '`ss`.`wwwwwww`']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below regex. Greedy nature of `.*` from left to right is what caused issue.
Instead you should search for [^`]*

```
`[^`]*?`\.`[^`]*?`
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6QRJT/4)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that
`.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators) even whitespaces.
Also as you're already using `*` which  means either 0 or unlimited occurrences,not sure you need to use `?`.
So this seems to work:

```
\`\S+\`[.]\`\S+\`
```

where `\S` is any non-whitespace character.
You always can check you regexes using https://regex101.com